# Expectation for continuous random variable $X$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, definition, expected-value

Both [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details) and the notes from my class state that for a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with density distribution function $f$, its exceptation can be computed as

$$E[X]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}xf(x)dx$$

This confuses me. In the discrete case one computes the expectation as

$$E[X]=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} X(\omega)P(\omega)$$

which makes sense and points to an intuitive notion of area where each "block" being added has $X(\omega)$ as its width and $P(\omega)$ as its height, but in the continuous case the term $X(\omega)$ is not present, why? Should it not be

$$E[X]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}X(t)f(t)dt$$

---

**Edit:** I know little measure theory, but someone who posted (and now deleted) an answer pointed to the fact that the definition of expectation is

$$E[X]=\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)dP$$

and according to [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes.pdf) paper (page 40) it gives the corresponding result in the discrete case, and in the continuous one the expression is defined as

$$\sup\Big\{\int \phi dP: 0\leq \phi \leq X(\omega), \phi \ \text{simple}\Big\}=\sup\Big\{\sum_{k=1}^Nc_kP(E_k)\Big\}$$

Taking $p_0\leq p_1\leq \ldots \leq p_N\in\mathbb{R}$ and letting $E_k=[p_{k-1},p_k]$, the last expression can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=1}^Nc_k\big[ F_X(p_k)-F_X(p_{k-1})\big]$$

where $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. Making the intervals really small gives $[F_X(p_k)-F_X(p_{k-1})]\sim f_X(p_k)(p_k-p_{k-1})=f_X(p_k)\Delta_k$ and $c_k\sim X(p_k)$. Putting it all together:

$$\sum_{k=1}^Nc_k\big[ F_X(p_k)-F_X(p_{k-1})\big]\rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^NX(p_k)f_X(p_k)\Delta_k\rightarrow \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}X(t)f_X(t)dt$$

Comment: The expectation calculated as in the first formula you quoted holds only for random variable with density! It's not the general case

Comment: The general definition of an expectation is the measure theoretic one: on a probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$: $E(X)=\int_\Omega X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$. In *Probability with Martingales* by D. Williams, it is proven that the general definition yields the familiar formula whenever the RV permits a probability density function (eg when the CDF is absolutely continuous). It also includes the discrete case, as counting measures allow us to look at summations as integrals.